# EL expression: passing null as value of BigDecimal field

Tags: java, jsp, el

I have class with `BigDecimal` property. When I bind to it EL expression and passing null - `valueExpression.set(context, null)`, new value of property becomes to be `BigDecimal.ZERO`.

Is there any way to pass null to `BigDecimal` field without converting it to zero?

Comment: Are BigDecimal handled in EL expression ? I can see Boolean, Integer, Float and String and Null.

Comment: Yes, they're handled, but sometimes in unexpected way - when you will try to perform math operations on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be running Tomcat of at least version 6.0.16 or a fork of it like JBoss AS. Tomcat's builtin Apache EL parser will indeed do that for all classes extending [`Number`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html). You need to add the following VM argument to disable this behaviour (which is indeed unintuitive, but unfortunately strictly as per the EL spec):

```
-Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false
```

See also [JSP/EL spec issue 184](http://java.net/jira/browse/JSP_SPEC_PUBLIC-184) and [Tomcat issue 42385](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43285).

Comment: This one affected us when migrating to Tomcat 8, so to help others just want to note that (in that tomcat version) it's set **false by default** - [link](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/systemprops.html)

Comment: Also, i did not find anything alike for JUEL implementation of EL. It just converts to zero without possibility to change this behavior.