# Passing empty string to .tag with a java.lang.Integer attribute results in 0 (not null)

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I have a .tag file with an attribute of type java.lang.Integer like so:

```
<%@ attribute name="userId" required="true" type="java.lang.Integer"%>
```

When passing in an empty string to this tag, the attribute ends up with a value of **0** instead of **null** (as I would have hoped using **java.lang.Integer** and all).

Am I missing something?  Is there any way to force the attribute value to be **null** in this case?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that if the type conversion fails (i.e. the value passed in won't parse as an Integer, so Integer.parseInt throws a NumberFormatException) then the attribute is initialised to 0. This kind of makes sense as it distinguishes between that case and a null object reference.

How about having a String attribute instead in your .tag file? You can then test it's value (for null or empty etc) and convert to an Integer as necessary.

Comment: Defining the attribute as a String does work as you have suggested, I was just hoping I could force the exception when calling the tag with a bum value.

Comment: This is explained quite clearly here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9771260/375025. Its related to the version of Tomcat that you're using. The behaviour is fixed with Tomcat 8, or you can set a system property: -Dorg.apache.el.parser.COERCE_TO_ZERO=false